# MYSQL Trigger Update is not working as supposed

Tags: mysql, function, triggers, match

I have created an update trigger in MySQL Community Server 5.5.16 but when I try to update statement: `Update Account set credit = 100 Where Number = 14001455;` I get an error "ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row". I do not understand why I get this error and what's wrong with my code:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER t_creditexceed AFTER UPDATE ON Account
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    DECLARE n_overdraft INTEGER;
    DECLARE n_balance INTEGER;
    DECLARE n_number INTEGER;
    DECLARE n_credit INTEGER;
    DECLARE credit_exception condition for SQLSTATE '07030';

    SELECT balance, credit, number INTO n_balance, n_credit, n_number
    FROM Account;
    IF ((n_balance < (-n_credit)) AND (n_balance >= 1.1 * (-n_credit)))
    THEN
    SET n_overdraft = n_balance + n_credit;
    INSERT INTO overdraft (account_no, over_draft) VALUES (n_number, n_overdraft);
    END IF;
    IF (n_balance < 1.1 *(- n_credit))
    THEN signal credit_exception;
    END IF;
END;
|
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is the statement: `SELECT balance, credit, number INTO n_balance, n_credit, n_number FROM Account;` - it probably returns more than 1 row, and thus MySQL cannot load the values into the variables you defined.

Not sure about your intention, but maybe you were looking for `NEW.` and `OLD.` values?

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
SELECT balance, credit, number INTO n_balance, n_credit, n_number
FROM Account;
```

does not have a WHERE clause, so you'd be selecting ALL `Account` records into variables, which is where the error message comes from. Selecting into variables only works when you have a single result row - with multiple rows, MySQL has no way of knowing which row you want out of the result set. It won't pick for you.

Answer (score 1):

The initial "select balance, credit, number" is returning more than one row.